# Silverlight Deployment Issue

Tags: silverlight, linq-to-sql

I have a Silverlight Application which has Linq to Sql to connect to a database. This also uses RIA services.

This is working fine when running locally however when I host it onto the server it just hangs. I have figured out that it can not connect to the Domain context and get the data from the database (which it needs to load).

I have tried:

-Installing RIA services onto the server (not full installation as dont want to add VS2010 onto it)
- Installing Silverlight 4 & any toolkits on the server
- Changing all my DomainServuce DLL's to Read only

Comment: Do you provide a connection string directly to your web-based SQL server in your web.config?

Comment: What happens if you surf to the service url manually? Anything in the event log?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the DOT.NET Version on the server coresponds to the version used to build your app?

Answer (score 0):

To facilitate testing issues like this it can be helpful to have a development server that has Visual Studio installed to allow you to do more debugging on a server...

Answer (score 0):

I run into this every time I deploy.  Then I remember to go to the web project references at set Copy Local to True for all of the System.ServiceModel.* assemblies.  In some cases, you may also need to set Copy Local to True on System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.

Good luck!

-Michael

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a problem with Cross-Domain access issue.

1. Create a file crossdomain.xml on the RIA service folder (server) and include following xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
   <cross-domain-policy>
       <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
   </cross-domain-policy>
   ```
2. Create another file clientaccesspolicy.xml with following XML

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <access-policy>
     <cross-domain-access>
       <policy>
         <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
           <domain uri="*"/>
         </allow-from>
         <grant-to>
           <resource include-subpaths="true" path="/"/>
         </grant-to>
       </policy>
     </cross-domain-access>
   </access-policy>
   ```